Receiving an error: "function components cannot be given refs" when trying to add a download option for a generated QR code
I am receiving an error in react when trying to add a download option for a generated QR code. The error states "Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?". Note that I am new to react and not sure where to implement this "forwardRef" option. Here is my code:
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Button,
  ToggleButtonGroup,
  ToggleButton,
  InputGroup,
  FormControl,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import QRCode from "qrcode.react";

const LinkQRPage = () => {
  const [link, setLink] = useState(""); // State for input link
  const [qrOptions, setQROptions] = useState({
    size: 256,
    bgColor: "#FFFFFF",
    fgColor: "#000000",
    level: "H",
    includeMargin: false,
    imageOptions: {
      type: "url",
      src: "",
      file: null,
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
    },
  });

  const qrCanvasRef = useRef(null); // Ref to hold QR code canvas element

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
      "Generating QR code with link:",
      link,
      "and options:",
      qrOptions
    );
  };

  // Function to handle input change for link
  const handleLinkChange = (e) => {
    setLink(e.target.value);
  };

  // Function to handle input change for styling options
  const handleOptionChange = (name, value) => {
    setQROptions((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // Function to handle file upload for image
  const handleFileUpload = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setQROptions((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          imageOptions: {
            ...prevState.imageOptions,
            type: "file",
            src: reader.result,
            file: file,
          },
        }));
      };
    }
  };

  // Function to handle QR code size change
  const handleQRSizeChange = (e) => {
    const newSize = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    setQROptions((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      size: newSize,
    }));
  };

  // Function to handle downloading the QR code
  const handleDownload = () => {
    if (qrCanvasRef.current !== null) {
      const canvas = qrCanvasRef.current._canvas; // Accessing the canvas element
      const imageDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = imageDataUrl;
      downloadLink.download = "QRCode.png";
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container className="mt-5 mb-5">
      <Row>
        <Col md={8} className="left-side-qr">
          <h1>LinkQR</h1>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="linkInput" className="form-label">
                Link
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="linkInput"
                placeholder="Enter your link"
                value={link}
                onChange={handleLinkChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="sizeInput" className="form-label">
                QR Code Size
              </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                className="form-control"
                id="sizeInput"
                name="size"
                value={qrOptions.size}
                onChange={handleQRSizeChange}
                min="64"
                max="256"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="bgColorInput" className="form-label">
                Background Color
              </label>
              <input
                type="color"
                className="form-control"
                id="bgColorInput"
                name="bgColor"
                value={qrOptions.bgColor}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleOptionChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="fgColorInput" className="form-label">
                Foreground Color
              </label>
              <input
                type="color"
                className="form-control"
                id="fgColorInput"
                name="fgColor"
                value={qrOptions.fgColor}
                onChange={(e) =>
                  handleOptionChange(e.target.name, e.target.value)
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label className="form-label">Image Type</label>
              <ToggleButtonGroup
                type="radio"
                name="imageType"
                value={qrOptions.imageOptions.type}
                onChange={(value) => handleOptionChange("imageType", value)}
              >
                <ToggleButton id="url-toggle" value="url">
                  URL
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton id="file-toggle" value="file">
                  Upload
                </ToggleButton>
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
            </div>
            {qrOptions.imageOptions.type === "url" && (
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="imageSrcInput" className="form-label">
                  Image Source (URL)
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="imageSrcInput"
                  name="imageSrc"
                  placeholder="Enter image URL"
                  value={qrOptions.imageOptions.src}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleOptionChange("imageSrc", e.target.value)
                  }
                />
              </div>
            )}
            {qrOptions.imageOptions.type === "file" && (
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="imageFileInput" className="form-label">
                  Upload Image
                </label>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="imageFileInput"
                  name="imageFile"
                  onChange={handleFileUpload}
                />
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="imageWidthInput" className="form-label">
                Image Width (Optional)
              </label>
              <InputGroup>
                <FormControl
                  type="number"
                  id="imageWidthInput"
                  name="imageWidth"
                  placeholder="Width"
                  value={qrOptions.imageOptions.width}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleOptionChange("imageWidth", e.target.value)
                  }
                  aria-label="Image width"
                />
                <InputGroup.Text>px</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="imageHeightInput" className="form-label">
                Image Height (Optional)
              </label>
              <InputGroup>
                <FormControl
                  type="number"
                  id="imageHeightInput"
                  name="imageHeight"
                  placeholder="Height"
                  value={qrOptions.imageOptions.height}
                  onChange={(e) =>
                    handleOptionChange("imageHeight", e.target.value)
                  }
                  aria-label="Image height"
                />
                <InputGroup.Text>px</InputGroup.Text>
              </InputGroup>
            </div>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Generate QR Code
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Col>

        <Col
          md={4}
          className="right-side-qr d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        >
          <div style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
            <h1>Preview</h1>
            <div style={{ width: "80%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
              <QRCode
                ref={qrCanvasRef} // Ref to access QR code canvas element
                size={256} // Fixed size for the preview
                value={link}
                bgColor={qrOptions.bgColor}
                fgColor={qrOptions.fgColor}
                includeMargin={qrOptions.includeMargin}
                imageSettings={{
                  src: qrOptions.imageOptions.src,
                  x: null,
                  y: null,
                  height: qrOptions.imageOptions.height,
                  width: qrOptions.imageOptions.width,
                  excavate: true,
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mt-3">
              <Button variant="success" onClick={handleDownload}>
                Download QR Code
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default LinkQRPage;


I tried multiple suggestions, but unsure where to implement it. Just looking for advice or pointers in the right direction.

The issue comes from trying to add ref to custom functional component QRCode. As the error sais Function components cannot be given refs. The only way would be to pass a ref via forwardRef and only if that component supports it. Docs on forwardRef https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef
